# How can I run a list of date strings through a function and return the results of each item as one concatonated string?

Tags: python, function, list-comprehension

I need to write a program that validates a list of given dates. Each date from the list validated needs to return either a "-" if it is valid or the end digit of the year if it is not. These returns need to be appended to 'Results = ""' as one string to complete the problem.

So I got the date validation down, but now I am stuck trying to figure out how to properly run the list program through my validation program so every item is returned to create a new Results string

So far I have this:

```py
def ListofDates (): #this is the program my teach gave us. The validation included seemed confusing to me.
    DateList = []
    for mon in range (1,13):
        Yr,Feb = 2001,0
        if (mon == 2):
            Feb = 2
            if Yr%400==0 or Yr%100!=0 and Yr%4==0:  # if leap year, make Feb subtract one less day
                Feb = 1
        MonSt = "{0:0>2}".format(mon)
        DateList = DateList + [MonSt +"/00/"+str(Yr)] + [MonSt +"/01/"+str(Yr)]
        ShortMon = (mon-1)%7%2 # (teacher comment) Equals 1 or 30 (or less) day months and 0 for 31 day months
        MaxDay = 31 - ShortMon - Feb
        DateList = DateList + [MonSt +"/"+ str(MaxDay+1) +"/"+ str(Yr)] + [MonSt +"/"+ str(MaxDay) +"/"+str(Yr)]
    DateList = DateList + ["02/29/1900"] + ["02/29/2000"]
    DateList = DateList + ["00/29/2000"] + ["02/29/2400"]
    DateList = DateList + ["13/29/2000"] + ["12/31/2500"]
    DateList = DateList + ["01/01/2501"] + ["02/28/0001"]
    DateList = DateList + ["02/28/0000"] + ["02/29/400"]
    return (DateList)

def dayMonth_is_valid(month,day,year):
    if month in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]:
        return 1 <= day <= 31
    if month in [4,6,9,11]:
        return 1 <= day <= 30
    if month == 2:
        if year % 400 == 0:
            return 1<=day<=29
        if year % 4 == 0:
            if year % 100 == 0:
                return 1 <= day <= 28
            else:
                return 1 <= day <= 29
        else:
            return 1<= day <=28

def year_is_valid(year):
    return 1 <= year <=2500

def date_is_valid(date):
    month,day,year = map(int, date.split("/"))

    if dayMonth_is_valid(month,day,year) and year_is_valid(year)==True:
        print ("-")
    else:
        print (str(year%10)) #is there a better way to do this?

def validate_date_list():
    dates = ListofDates()
    Results = ""
    for date in dates:
        Results.append (date_is_valid(date))

validate_date_list()
```

I didn't actually finish the result part of if because I couldn't even get the dates to run through the validation program. Also I know that strings can't be appended. I was thinking I would make results a list then append that and then join it (but that seems like a lot of steps)

So my validation program works fine but I can't figure out how to run that list through it.
Does this have to do with the format?
Is 'dates' read as a list to begin with?

Also, for the returning "-" or str(year%10): is that the best spot to complete this step?
Or should I return true/false then generate the string in the main function?

How can I run each individual item from the 'dates' list through 'date_is_valid()' as the appropriate variable to complete that function?

I looked at different methods of list comprehension and for statements but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Please rephrase the question so it is clear and concise. Include the input, output, desired output and the code from your attempt.

Comment: I tried to rewrite it more clearly

Answer (score 1):

You need to **`return`** the values instead of printing them. Also, you can use `str[-1]` for returning the end digit of the year instead of `%10`.

```
def date_is_valid(date):

    month,day,year = map(int, date.split("/"))
    
    if dayMonth_is_valid(month,day,year) and year_is_valid(year)==True:
        return ("-")
    else:
        return (str(year)[-1])

def validate_date_list():
    dates = ListofDates()
    Results = ""
    for date in dates:
        Results += date_is_valid(date)

validate_date_list()
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks for pointing that out! I forgot to change it back to return after testing it. So how do I pass a list through this?

Comment: Thank you! I will try this way out too! between Shrada's and Anatoliy's answers which is preferred in pythonic coding?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to return True or False from `date_is_valid` and then use `join` method with generator:

```py
dates = ListofDates()
results = ''.join('-' if date_is_valid(date) else date[-1] for date in dates)
```

By the way, expression `== True` is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you! Does calling a function like this automatically result in a True or False value, hence making ==True redundant?

Comment: This worked BTW. Also I got "1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-0-0-0-1-0-" as my answer. What was happening in the ListofDates() that added all those additional entires? I see Dateslist + but I don't see how this adds 48 additional entries besides the ones manually entered. I am just curious tho... this is extra curricular

Comment: Shrada's method worked too! Your's has less lines, which I like, but would there be an optimization preference in python?